# Removing comma from IntegerTextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc, numeric-textbox

I have a question about the IntegerTextBoxFor from Telerik Extensions for MVC.  I'm currently trying to remove the use of commas from it.  Currently here is what I have.

Editor Template called Int32.cshtml

```
@model System.Int32
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI

@Html.Telerik().IntegerTextBoxFor(model => model)
```

Model

```
[NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.ReturnRequest.List.SearchOrderId")]
public int SearchOrderId { get; set; }
```

I have tried adding [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:g}")] to the model but it has done nothing.  I also tried using 0:#####, 0:00000, and 0:n.

Comment: @JasonEvans I think problem is related to UI. When Telerik IntegerTextBoxFor get used to display SearchOrderId it try to format number with DecimalSeparator.

Comment: You can try to set the `NumberGroupSeparator` to `""` with `@Html.Telerik().IntegerTextBoxFor(model => model).NumberGroupSeparator("")`

Comment: @JasonEvans Why do the work that Telerik already did?  It would be reinventing the wheel for no reason.

Comment: Thank you @nemesv!  It worked right away.  Go ahead and post the answer and I'll give you credit.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the group separator with calling the `NumberGroupSeparator` method on the `IntegerTextBoxFor(model => model)`.

So if you don't need the separator you can set it to the empty string:

```
@Html.Telerik().IntegerTextBoxFor(model => model).NumberGroupSeparator("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Telerik don't have this "NumberGroupSeparator" method on Kendo UI.

```
@(Html.Kendo().IntegerTextBoxFor(model => model)
```